# Creating <rich:modalPanel> dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, richfaces

How to create a rich:modalPanel dynamically? I need to click one button and generate a floating panel. The catch is, if I click the button, there should be created a second panel, and the first one should remain on its place. I've tried using ui:repeat and reRender, but this overwrites the first panel when I generate a second one.

Comment: Why would you need more than one `modelPanel`? Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of 'modal'? Do you want multiple dialogs over the page or a single modal dialog with a dynamic number of sections within it or something different again?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<c:forEach />
```

For an explanation on why you should use the 'c' tag instead of 'ui' read [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).

Alternatively, bind the parent component and create the modal panel programmatically using java. See an example [here](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/michael_bevels/dynamic_forms_using_jsf.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modal panel opened, you won't be able to click any buttons (unless the button is on the modal panel). RichFaces 4 has a pop-up panel which can be modal or non-modal. Using the non-modal version, you can open multiple pop-ups.